# Растянуть любые <iframe> до родительского элемента

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe

Имеется в БД коллекция iframe с прописанными атрибутами, которые средствами php вставляются в страницу.
  Есть ли решение которое позволит сделать все iframe фиксированного размера, или придется писать обработчик, который на лету изменяет атрибуты iframe?
 Какое решение? 
 Если у кого то есть готовый обработчик- поделитесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы перебить значения установленные в атрибутах, можно поставить флаг "!important" в свойствах css.

К примеру,

```
 html:
 <iframe width="500px"></iframe>
```

будет слабее, чем

```
 css:
  iframe{
     width: 300px !important;
  }
```

Comment: У атрибутов приоритет минимальный.

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно просто сделать так, будет работать и без важности:

```
..css:
  iframe{
       width: 300px;
     //width: 300px !important;
  }
```

А вот резинить их пропорционально по ширине и высоте - сложнее.

Comment: Да благодарю- ответ Влада сработал для моих целей. Но для ищущих ответы в поиске, если не затруднит, напишите, как пропорционально резинить.